# How can I override the default uncaught exception dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

When an exception goes uncaught in a .NET app, the virtual machine displays an error message to the user. I'd like to be able to display my own error message, without having to put a `catch` block at the top level of my app (because that makes debugging uncaught exceptions more tedious).

Right now I display my own error dialog in an `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event listener, but the .NET-created dialog still shows up. I'd also like to avoid `Environment.FailFast` as that would bypass my `finally` blocks (to which I'm still somewhat attached).

Comment: That's a feature of the JIT. I'm not sure that there is a way to modify it...

Comment: I'd probably create a production mode / development mode configuration variable to switch between viewing your own dialog (and catching) in the top level and not viewing it. It's also a good idea in general for debugging...

Comment: It is definitely possible, I remembered Red Gate has done something in this field. See this [image](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/assets/images/error_reporting_dialog.png) and the related product [page](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/learn-more/screenshots). I am not sure if they have a free version, but they have done this, so there must be a way!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014562/whats-the-difference-between-application-threadexception-and-appdomain-currentd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is WinForms, you have to handle [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) to catch them all. Some exceptions filter into one and others into the other.

There was a similar (but not exact duplicate) question here that should help: [C# - WinForms - Exception Handling for Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524381/c-sharp-winforms-exception-handling-for-events)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms has a built-in exception handler that by default catches an unhandled managed exception when no debugger is attached, and the exception occurs during window message processing, and *jitDebugging* = false in App.Config. It then shows a dialog to the end-user and prevents app termination.

You can change the registry setting *DbgJitDebugLaunchSetting* under **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\.NetFramework**. This has one of three values of which I'm aware:

- 0: shows user dialog asking "debug or terminate".
- 1: lets exception through for CLR to deal with.
- 2: launches debugger specified in *DbgManagedDebugger* registry key.

In Visual Studio, go to *Tools > Options > Debugging > JIT* to set this key to 0 or 2. But a value of 1 is usually what you want on an end-user's machine

(See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ac5yxx6(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ac5yxx6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

How about a similar pattern that is in WP7?

```
    // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // do stuff
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this lets me display a custom message.